# Manga where the male protagonist summons 3 goddesses in front of many people

Tags: story-identification, manga

I can't really remember any information but I know that he did it in a place with a giant clock or something similar. I saw it once and forgot to take a screenshot so right now I'm searching but my efforts are in vain.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you remember any details of the appearance of any of the characters?  Was it in colour?

Comment: The protagonist is male and has a short black hair with an ahoge, I think. The manga is b&w. I remember the goddesses saying that he was the only one who was able to summon 3 gods at the same time when he summoned them.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is *[Tou no Kanri o Shite Miyou](https://myanimelist.net/manga/115369/Tou_no_Kanri_wo_Shitemiyou)* or *Let's manage the tower*

In Chapter 34 of the manga, the main character summons 3 goddesses to bless a temple. One of the three says that he is the first man to ever summon a god. The temple has a circular hole in the front wall that the goddess are summoned in front of, which could be mistaken for a clock tower.

[image: 3 Goddesses congratulating their summoner]
[image: 3 Goddesses blessing a temple]